# Fatal error: Cannot access empty property - function connect()

Tags: php

When I use this PHP coding, I get the following error:

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /connection.php on line 29

```
class connectionClass
{

    var $host = '';
    var $user = '';
    var $password = '';
    var $db = '';
    var $con

    function __construct($flag)
    {
        if($flag == "local"):
            $this->host = "localhost";
            $this->user = "root";
        elseif($flag == "remote"):
            $this->host = "192.168.1.2";
            $this->user = "root";
        else:
            echo "Incorrect connection flag.";
        endif;

        $this->password = $password;
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    function connect()
    {
        $con = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($this->db, $con) or die(mysql_error());
    }

}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have these lines? $this->password = $password; $this->db = $db;? $password and $db are not defined since they don't exist within the scope of the function.

Comment: Also, this is the best time to migrate to PDO or mysqli as you haven't done much with this class yet.

Answer (score 4):

What is with the alternative syntax in a class? Bad practice -- you are not writing a template.  Use curly brackets.

Most likely your problem is here:

```
 $this->password = $password;
 $this->db = $db;
```

You assign $password to your class variable, but $password is not a parameter in the constructor.  So your $this->password is null.  Same problem with $this->db.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! They were extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in your '__construct' function.

Look at the line 23, '$this->db = $db;'. Make sure you define the local variable $db with a value.

Note: The definition of variable '$password' (line 22) is missing too. Make sure you define that too with a value.